# Who named Luke Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars

Who named Luke Skywalker "Luke" according to canon?

- Padme before death?
- Bail Organa after birth?
- Obi-Wan before giving to Larses?
- Larses?
- Some other option I missed?

Comment: What's up with downvotes (and no comments to boot?)

Comment: You've obviously not seen, or paid much attention to, Episode III.  Presuming anyone who would ask such a question has done any minimal research at all (i.e.: Reviewed all the movies.), the answer is fairly common knowledge.

Comment: Wait...  You have over 36k site rep, and more than 1k rep in [tag:star-wars] alone?  How did you *not* know this?!?!

Comment: @Iszi - I'm not Slytherincess. I have occasional memory lapses. Some are deliberate, as is the case with Ep 1 :) I haven't noteced other 100% obvious-from-source questions being majorly downvoted before, and trust me, SFF is choke full of them.

Comment: Occasional memory lapses?  Occasional?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Padmé gave Luke and Leia their first names before she died. This is shown in Star Wars Episode III.

> After Kenobi defeated Vader, and left him for dead, he took Amidala to a medical facility on Polis Massa, where she delivered twins, a boy, Luke, and a girl, Leia, whom she both named.
>
> -- http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala

From Episode III:

> MEDICAL DROID: It's a boy.
>
> PADME: Luke . . .
>
> PADME can only offer up a faint smile. She struggles to touch the baby
> on the forehead.
>
> MEDICAL DROID: ... and a girl.
>
> PADME: . . . Leia.
>
> -- http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html

The name Skywalker comes from Shmi Skywalker, Anakin's mother.

> The Skywalker family was a Force-sensitive Human bloodline whose first known member was Shmi Skywalker.
>
> -- http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker_family

From Episode I draft script, the introduction of Anakin, then (later) Shmi:

> A disheveled boy, ANAKIN SKYWALKER, runs in from the junk yard. He is about
> nine years old, very dirty, and dressed in rags. WATTO raises a hand, and
> ANAKIN flinches.
>
> Anakin's mother, SHMI SKYWALKER, a warm, friendly woman of forty, enters
> from her work area and is startled to see the room full of people.
>
> -- http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html

Comment: Is the Wikia stuff referenced (e.g. script)? I don't mean to go all Slytherincessy here, but I don't necessarily trust Wiki info when I'm looking for pure canon

Comment: @DVK I've seen Episode 3 in the past few months, this happens at the end of Episode 3, just like the Wikia and answer says.

Comment: @DVK - "This is shown in Star Wars Episode III" should be all the canon sourcing you need.

Comment: @DVK I've added some additional supporting material to the answer. These are just scripts found on the Internet at large, I've no paper copies to reference. :-)

Comment: @jeff - imsdb is reliable enough for scripts in my experience. +1 and accept!

Comment: @DVK Just watch Episode III.  For that matter, please review all of Episodes I-VI before asking such questions again.  It'll save you some down-votes.

Comment: @Iszi - do you also downvote every other question that can be answered from the script of the movie or the text of teh book? I can give you a list of several hundred on SFF so you can tell me how many you downvoted and how many you snidely commented on.

Comment: @DVK Perhaps my comments were a bit harshly phrased, and for that I apologize.  But it may be worth noting that I'm not the only one who down-voted the question, here.  4 down-votes total is pretty rough.

Comment: @Iszi - the comment above was really to all downvoter, not just you. I've never seen a question being penalized before for being "can be answered by watching a movie", especially a minor forgettable plot point. And voting specifically because the user is a high-rep user for SW is WAY contrary to the whole point of SE - the votes should be on post quality, and not who posted it.

Comment: Asking people to review I-III just because they have a question? You're a cruel man Iszi...

Comment: If you want an actual source, here you go:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeoGfNEGVS0