# Why the name "Luke" of Luke Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

Luke is the [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_(name)) of *Lucius*, a [roman name](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lucius#Latin). With the advent of Christianity, it has been mostly associated with [Luke the Evangelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_the_Evangelist), and hence has a strong Christian connotation, particularly in the Occidental culture (where it's mostly found).

Meanwhile, as far as my experience of SW universe tells me, there is an active effort in stories of omitting references to any human-known major religion. Thus, I find odd that who is allegedly the most central character of all the series has a Christian-associated name. It is hard to find other instances of this in SW. Another example is [Tobias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias), a Hebrew name, [part of the Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Tobit), and the first name of the Solo character [Tobias Beckett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tobias_Beckett).

What is the justification (perhaps by George Lucas himself) of naming the main character of the whole series with a very familiar western (and popularly Christian) name, amid an evident effort of making no references to human-Earth religions?

PS: I am not judging Christianity in any sense. I just want to understand how to reconcile the above issue with the more general naming convention in SW.

PS2: [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16147/who-named-luke-skywalker) (or others) have no relevant answer to the one here.

Comment: Luke and Tobias are far from the only _Star Wars_ characters with Christian or Roman names. Ezra Bridger, Jan Dodonna (Jan is a form of John), Galen Erso, Cornelius Evazan, Kit Fisto (Kit is a form of Christopher), Janus Greegatus, Gideon Hask, Ben Quadinaros (Ben is a form of Benjamin), Max Rebo (Max is a form of Maximilian) and Hera Syndulla, for example.

Comment: @Jenayah So your hypothesis is that, even though GL might have not explicitly stated that the name comes from his surname, the phrase plus the coincidence is too great for being any other reasonable explanation?

Comment: @luchonacho pretty much, yeah. And in any case, if someone finds a George Lucas quote stating "yup, I totally named Luke after my own name", it rather belongs in an answer to the question linked above. Gather all interconnected info in the same place rather than have it scattered around, as much as possible :)

Comment: @MikeScott - While the spelling's different, and the pronunciation is inconsistent, there also Leia (variant of Leah, wife of Jacob).